# How does Clostridium perfringens cause target hemolysis?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, bacteriology, enzymes

I am studying microbiology as a part of my course and I was studying *Clostridium perfringens*.

While studying its hemolytic characteristics, I came to know that it causes target hemolysis (i.e. zone of beta hemolysis due to Theta toxin surrounded by zone of alpha hemolysis by alpha toxin).

Surprisingly alpha toxin has a Phospholipase-C (PL-C) like action. Isn't PL-C supposed to be Beta-hemolytic? Since it will lyse the RBC membrane?

[Alpha-hemolysis is supposed to be conversion of hemoglobin to methemoglobin]